# React Context: Sessionstorage data in developer tools appears but appears blank in navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-context, session-storage

I'm using React Context to store data into sessionstorage for the purposes of logging in and out. I'm saving three things: IDContext for saving the user's ID, UserNameContext for saving the user's username, and AdminContext to simply see if the logged in user is an admin or not. I want to display the logged in user's username on the navigation bar such as (Welcome, {user}) but instead it just displays as (Welcome, {}). I checked the sessionstorage via the developer tools, and it shows

```
username:""user""
```

So why exactly does it show up blank on the navigation bar, am I not grabbing the data correctly?

auth.js:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const UserNameContext = createContext();
export const IDContext = createContext();
export const AdminContext = createContext();

export function useUserName() {
  return useContext(UserNameContext);
}

export function useID() {
  return useContext(IDContext);
}

export function useAdmin() {
  return useContext(AdminContext);
}
```

navbar.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useID, useUserName, useAdmin } from "../context/auth";

function Navigation(props) {
    const { IDTokens } = useID();
    const { usernameTokens } = useUserName();
    const { adminTokens } = useAdmin();

    function adminNav() {
        return (
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to={`/${usernameTokens}`}>Welcome, {usernameTokens}</Link>
                    <Link to="/logout">Log Out</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    function loggedInNav() {
        return (
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to={`/${usernameTokens}`}>Welcome, {usernameTokens}</Link>
                    <Link to="/logout">Log Out</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    function guestNav() {
        return(
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="md">
            <Container>
                <Link to="/">Flaskagram</Link>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                {IDTokens && adminTokens ? (
                    adminNav()
                ) : IDTokens ? (
                    loggedInNav()
                ) : (
                    guestNav()
                )}
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need three separate contexts for storing those 3 pieces of information. To make your user object accessible from anywhere in your app, add this line inside App.js (at the beginning of the App function):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState();
```

Make sure the useState hook is imported in App.js, as well as UserContext from wherever you will define your context (in your case, I believe it is auth.js).

Then, wrap all the jsx elements that are returned from App.js with the context provider like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  // any other code you might have here

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      // all your app's components here
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In auth.js, this is all you need:

```
import React from "react";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

Wherever you set the user object (most likely on your login page), just use the following line to access the setUser function (and don't forget to import UserContext):

```
const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
```

Now, in navbar.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import UserContext from "../context/auth";

function Navigation() {
  const {
    user: { username, isAdmin },
  } = useContext(UserContext);

  function adminNav() {
    return (
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Link to={`/${username}`}>Welcome, {username}</Link>
          <Link to="/logout">Log Out</Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    );
  }

  function loggedInNav() {
    return (
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Link to={`/${username}`}>Welcome, {username}</Link>
          <Link to="/logout">Log Out</Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    );
  }

  function guestNav() {
    return (
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Link to="#">Placeholder</Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
          <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="md">
      <Container>
        <Link to="/">Flaskagram</Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        {username && isAdmin
          ? adminNav()
          : username
          ? loggedInNav()
          : guestNav()}
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

In order for this implentation to work, when you log the user in, the user object must have the properties of `isAdmin` and `username` set so that they can be accessed in the navbar. The `isLoggedIn` property is unnecessary because if the username property isn't null, it means that a user must be logged in.

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I replace the applicable code with yours I get TypeError: Object(...)(...).user is undefined. And it points to the user variable in navbar.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have that item in your localstorage, you can just grab it using useEffect hook upon loading.

like this for example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const cachedUserName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
    if (cachedUserName ) {
      setUserName(cachedUserName);
    }
else {
...your logic
}
  }, [setUserName]);
```